# How to do automation testing for table view and scroll for specific cell in android using espresso?

Tags: android

automation testing for table view and scroll for specific cell ,that is rows and columns in android using espresso.
In table i am not able to scroll to specific cells ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This UI Automator

```js
 UiScrollable app2 = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
        app2.swipeLeft(200);

        UiScrollable app3 = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
        app3.swipeRight(200);

        UiScrollable app4 = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
        app4.swipeDown(200);

        UiScrollable app5 = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
        app5.swipeUp(200);
```